# Make dialogflow say today and not full date

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I'm building my first google assitant dialogflow.

In my intent, I request a date from the user.

I then want to put back this date in the response text of the intent.

If we are the 02/25/2018 and the user says "today", the response text will be "2018-02-25", said as "twenty eighteen zero two twenty five".

Is there a way that google assistant says the date in a more fluent way?
Meaning "Today", "Tomorrow", etc....

I'm using DialogForm API V1, and the language is French.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cool thing about this is you get a direct date, which is useful for things on your backend like storing a timestamp. However, as you note it is less useful for good VUI when you may expect to hear or see a relative time.

Although this is not directly supported in Dialogflow, it is not hard to find third-party libraries which fulfill this functionality.

Here is an example of using [Moment.JS](https://momentjs.com/), although I'm sure there are many more.

```
moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // Returns "6 years ago"
moment().calendar(); // Returns "Today at 4:48 PM"
moment().startOf('day').fromNow(); // Returns "17 hours ago"
```

Comment: You're totally right, third-party libraries are the solution, I should have thought of that. Thanks.